# How to AND and NOT in MongoDB $text search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I apologise in advance if this question has been asked, I searched without finding an answer.

I want to do a search in MongoDB, and I create the index and do something like

```
db.myCollection.runCommand( "text", { search: "myWord" } )
```

This works fine.

I can also do

```
db.myCollection.runCommand( "text", { search: "myWord1 myWord2" } )
```

and it will search both words.

Can I do the above search by asking that BOTH words be found? (I know I can do a search on the first word and then a search on the second on the result, but I wonder if there is a better way).

Also, is it possible to specify words to be rejected (for example, search for the word "test", but not for "testing").

I would like to know if I can do this in mongoDB without using external tools.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few options that you can use with text search to suit those needs. Consider the following documents:

```js
{ "text" : "cake" }
{ "text" : "sale" }
{ "text" : "sale cake" }
{ "text" : "cake sale" }
{ "text" : "dress sale" }
{ "text" : "cake sale monday" }
```

The default "list" of words is an **or** inclusion, but if you wan't an **and** inclusion you "quote" the words:

```js
db.words.find( { "$text": { "$search": "\"cake\" \"sale\"" } },{_id: 0})
{ "text" : "cake sale" }
{ "text" : "sale cake" }
{ "text" : "cake sale monday" }
```

If you want to **exclude** a word then you prefix with `-`:

```js
db.words.find( { "$text": { "$search": "\"cake\" \"sale\" -monday" } },{_id: 0})
{ "text" : "cake sale" }
{ "text" : "sale cake" }
```

And if you wanted part of that as an **exact phrase** then you "quote" the whole phrase:

```js
db.words.find( { "$text": { "$search": "\"cake sale\" -monday" } },{_id: 0})
{ "text" : "cake sale" }
```

Stemming words though does have an issue, so :

```js
db.words.find( { "$text": { "$search": "test -testing" } },{_id: 0})
```

Would not actually return a result.

See the documentation on the [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator for examples. Not all are there at the moment, but it's getting better.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. Now, can you tell me what the difference is between find and runCommand is. I thought that find would only find a key with the matching string, while runCommand will search for a string inside the text for a given key. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user79303 Good point. `runCommand` was required prior to MongoDB 2.6 but now text search has been integrated with the standard query engine along with other standardization on index interfaces. The usage of `runCommand` for text search is considered deprecated after this release and you should be using the `$text` operator in standard queries including aggregation pipeline. As shown in the answer, those are the available modifers to alter for **and** **phrases** and **word exclusion** that are currently supported.

Comment: -One last question. I tried using find instead of runCommand, but that will not return a score. Is there a way to get a score back using find like runCommand used to?

Comment: @user79303 Covered on the linked manual page. Read them, they are good. The section is ["Text Score"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-score) covering usage of the **`$meta`** operator.

Comment: Thank you, just found that. The weird thing, did they change also how the score is calculated in 2.6? I am getting different results, using the same word, if I do a search with find or runCommand. The score is different, (and therefore the order is different), though I am doing the same search (albeit with different methods).

Comment: Check this answer out as a workaround for supporting logical `AND` queries by wrapping each single search term with double quotes:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/35641331/1123355