# Is it possible to exclude/negate a phrase in mongo text search?

Tags: mongodb

Related to [How to AND and NOT in MongoDB $text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985464/how-to-and-and-not-in-mongodb-text-search)

Using the same document words collection for example:

```
{ "text" : "cake" }
{ "text" : "sale" }
{ "text" : "sale cake" }
{ "text" : "cake sale" }
{ "text" : "dress sale" }
{ "text" : "cake sale monday" }
```

**Is it possible to somehow explicitly negate the search phrase (not only one word), the following doesn't work when quoting the phrase:**

```
db.words.find( { "$text": { "$search": "-\"cake sale\"" } },{_id: 0})
```

Notice the minus sign (attempt of negation) `"-\"cake sale\""` as an intention to exclude documents containing exact phrase from result set.

Only way i can handle this is in further aggregation by using `$regex` to exclude already retrieved results from text search step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i must answer this with:

**Yes, it is possible, but you must have at least one inclusive phrase to be able to exclude another phrase.**

The following works:

```
db.words.find( { "$text": { "$search": "cake -\"cake sale\"" } },{_id: 0})
```