# How well do the search engines of databases like mongoDB and Postgres do compared to something like Elasticsearch? (in 2020)

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, sqlite, elasticsearch, search-engine

I am working on a website, where users can create entries into a database. These entries are all of the same form, so I was using Sqlite (with FTS5) so far, which is the only database I know ;)

However it is crucial that users can search these entries on the website. The full text search is working decently well (the users know approximately what they are looking for) but I need two improvements:

1. Wrong spelling should return the correct entry (I have seen the spellfix extension for sqlite for that, but I don't know how well it works)
2. more importantly if a user enters a few query words on the website I try to MATCH those with a sql query. If a user enters too many words, it will return 0 matches:

for example: if a user inputs "sars covid 19" into the search-bar:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TEST USING FTS5(SomeText);

INSERT INTO TEST(SomeText) VALUES 
('Covid 19');

SELECT SomeText 
FROM TEST 
WHERE SomeText MATCH 'sars covid 19';
```

=> 0 matches, but I would want it to return the 'covid 19' entry.

I realise that sqlite might be too simplistic for a database that needs to handle searches well. Now my question is: Do Postgres or MongoDB have search engines that include the functionality that I need? Or is it worth diving into solutions with Elastic Search etc.?

Most articles I found on this are 5-10 years old, so I am wondering what the current state of affairs is regarding search engines in databases. Any hints are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch  will work for sure. You only have to think about how you will index your document, and you will be able to find them the way you index them, in your context it seems that the default text will work with a match query :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html

MongoDb will work too in this simple case : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/ , but mongo wont work with tokenizer so if you need to upgrade your text search mongo will be limited.

Postgresql could do it, using the like but I am not familiar with enough, if you have 10k entries, it will be ok for sure, if you expect 1 millions, mongo or es would be better.

If you have to choose between mongodb and es, you have to be more specific in your question, for full text, es is really nice, having a lot of features, mongodb give some nice database tools too. Sometimes es will be better, sometimes mongo, depends of what you need. If you only want full text, es is a must.

Comment: Thank you very much! Regarding mongoDB, am I understanding this correctly that `db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "java coffee shop" } } )` would return all entries that have either "java", "coffee", or "shop" in them and then rank the results depending on many times they occur in the entry?

Comment: You can quote for the AND operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985464/how-to-and-and-not-in-mongodb-text-search

Comment: To be honest if you only have to work with text go es, mongo could be nice for infra / security.

Answer (score 1):

Combination es + mongodb work well, you index and perform full text search in es and you keep the original documents with some key fields indexed in mongodb...