# mongodb text search with OR connected strings containing spaces

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

The answer to this question (and a few others) gives some insight: [How to AND and NOT in MongoDB $text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985464/how-to-and-and-not-in-mongodb-text-search) , but there seems to be a case that does not work.

Quotes have a double meaning in text search strings, they define a fixed phrase and also a mandatory search string.

So, `'"some string"'` will only find the exact phrase, and `'"some" "string"'` will find all documents containing both, "some" and "string", but not necessarily together. Finally, omitting the quotes, `'some string'` will find documents with either "some" or "string" (or both).

How would I search for either of two strings, that have spaces in them?

Take for instance the search `'"some string" "other string"'`, which would find only documents that contain both of those phrases. But I want to find the documents, that contain `"some string"` or `"other string"` (or both).

To clarify, I am talking about text searches of the form:

```
db.words.find( { '$text': { '$search': 'some string' } }
```

I am using pymongo, but the mongodb query syntax should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid `$text` operator alone cannot solve this if you are not using MongoDB Atlas. As a workaround, you can use `$regex` along with `$text`. Like this:

```
db.words.find({"$text": {"$search": "some string other string"}, key: { $regex: /(some string)|(other string)/ }})
```

In this way, we are looking up all the words of the phrases via `$text` and then looking for the phrases, via `$regex`. This will use your `$text` index, and will be far more optimal than only using `$regex`.